# How many players does FIFA 18 support on a PS4 locally?

Tags: ps4, fifa-18

So my nephew wants a PS4 and FIFA 18 for Christmas and I face the trouble of conflicting information about how many players can play a local multiplayer game.

According to [playstation.com](https://www.playstation.com/de-de/games/ea-sports-fifa-18-ps4/) up to 4 players are supported.

According to the clerk at Saturn (German electronics market), only 2 players can play locally and anything beyond that is online.

Can somebody tell me which information is true, best based on personal experience?

Comment: I believe it's up to 4 players in local multiplayer and 2 in online multiplayer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely have 4 players locally and play 2 vs 2 for example.
I do this regularly with my friends :)

As for online, there are many options.
For example in Online Seasons you can play with a "Guest", meaning you have a friend locally and the 2 of you play vs someone online.